# extract specific data from resource without the header

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I'm trying to store and extract binary data in resources in c#
firstly I created the resource and stored some binary from byte array in it like this :

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\drive2\\cd\\somfile");
ResXResourceWriter reswrite = new ResXResourceWriter("resx.resx");
reswrite.AddResource("binary", data);
reswrite.Close();
```

then compiled it with resgen.exe :

```
ResGen.exe resx.resx
```

then compiled the resources file with the c# source code like this :

```
csc.exe /target:winexe program.cs /resource:resx.resources
```

and I'm using this code to get the data from the resourcce :

```
var resourecs = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
foreach(var res in resourecs)
{
  MessageBox.Show("resource : " + res);
  var res_stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(res);
  File.WriteAllBytes("out" + res, ReadFully(res_stream));
 }
```

the problem is that I don't get only the data I wrote in the section but with something like the resource header 
I want to dump only the bytes I wrote to "binary" in the resource

Comment: What is `ReadFully(stream)`?  Is that a method you wrote yourself?

Comment: yes it converts the whole stream to an array of bytes , I found the problem and it was that I'm using the wrong tool , ResourceManager was the right choice to do the job